# Retrieving data from parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am able to retrieve the array of strings into a list view but when I try and get the information stored in the "newStatus" column of parse and put it into a new activity "StatusDetailView", nothing comes out. The code I am providing is from a tutorial on Udemy and I am unable to reach the instructor.

When a row is clicked on the homepage list, the text from the row is displayed in another activity "StatusDetailView"

[image: OnListItemClick]

**StatusDetailView.java:**

```
public class StatusDetailView extends Activity {

String objectId;
protected TextView mStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_status_detail_view);

    // initialize
    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusDetailView);

    // Get the intent that started the activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    objectId = intent.getStringExtra("objectID"); // matches key in HomePageActivity

    // query data from parse
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Status");

    // Retrieve the object by id
    query.getInBackground("objectId", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Success we have a status
                String userStatus = parseObject.getString("newStatus"); // column
                mStatus.setText(userStatus);

            } else {
                // there was an error, advise user
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StatusDetailView.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I do run the app and I select a row, it takes me to the StatusDetailView Activity with an error but the list displays 8 rows:

[image: error]

[image: list of statuses]

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  How can i do that ?  I have the ParseLogInterceptor and this is what i get: Body : { "where": "{\"objectId\":\"objectId\"}",  "_method": "GET" then ... Body : { "results": [] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
query.getInBackground("objectId", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                       ^^^^^^^
 ..
}
```

passing `objectId` string as id instead of value of `objectId` String which is initialized using `intent.getStringExtra`.

To get it work change it as:

```
query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

 ...
}
```